# socketIO-client throwing error when connecting to the server

Tags: python, node.js, socket.io

I have written a python program to connect to the server using socketIO_client

I am using python 2.7

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO
myHost = 'localhost'
myPort = 8080
mySocket = SocketIO(myHost, myPort)
```

but it is throwing this 
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLB4S.png)

This is my server code on node.js

```js
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(8080);

app.use(express.static('public'));

var socket = require('socket.io');

var io = require('socket.io');

io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection);

function newConnection(socket){
 console.log('new connection: ' + socket.id)
}

console.log("My socket is running");
```

When I run the python code the server shows a new connection but python program shows the error (linked above)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you connect using javascript?

Comment: Yes, I am able to connect using Javascript